# Going up with a drip-feed system

Tags: drip-system

I currently have a very system drip feed system, consisting of a single pipe with small outlets like the one in this image.

[image]

It's working quite well, but I'd like to make a "branch" on it which would go up about 50 cms (20 inches) to drip into a pot.

What should I buy ? I'm kinda looking for keywords to input in a web search engine ^^ (bonus points if you can hint me the french names !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard drip irrigation systems like this are like Lego used to be a long time ago.  You can buy a couple dozen different shapes and sizes, to make all sorts of contraptions..

To branch off from this, I suggest using a 20 cm piece of ¼” (5 mm) diameter drip line, connected to the ½” line with a ¼” diameter straight connect.  Then put an emitter on the far end of the ¼” line.  To avoid buying more parts than you need (though to get these pieces you’ll have to get several), rather than buying the special tool that’s made for drip irrigation assembly, use any stabbing tool and be careful to poke through only one side of the ½” line.

Sorry I can’t help with the French, but ‘drip irrigation parts’ will get you many vendors in English.